# Can I ask for feedback on specific interface layouts?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a fairly poor eye for designs that I implement myself - I fall in love with features, and the screens of my iPhone apps slowly get very crowded. Also, after working on an interface for a very long time, it is hard for me to step back and look at it as a first time user would.  As such, it's very helpful to get real users to comment on the screen, and professional UX person's advice would be priceless.

My question is this - let's say I have a screen that I want to show to ux.stackexchange. **Is it acceptable to ask for "Does this screen look busy?" or "How can I streamline this interface?" questions**, or should I focus on a specific part of an interface that I would like to receive feedback on, such as "How to use gradients in a user-friendly way?", and then use my screen as a starting point for the question.

Your feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Requests for feedback / reviews specifically are not really suitable for this site. The reason for this is that UX.StackExchange (and all StackExchange sites) exist to provide benefit to all users, both the asker and future visitors. Critique of individual sites are too localised to be of benefit to anyone else other than the owner of that site.

However, it's quite likely that restructuring the way you ask the question would mean that it would be perfectly suitable.

For example, if one of the features you are a big fan of is something like endless scrolling pages then you can construct the question around that. So instead of asking *'I've included this in my homepage, is it good?'* you could phrase it more like *'On a page with lots of images is it useful to use endless scrolling, or should I go with traditional paging'* which would be more suitable and of benefit to other site users.

Comment: Adding your current design as an example is welcome and encouraged though; even if you're not requesting a critique specifically it helps us understand exactly what you're referring to